# Using Promise as return type in Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm using Flow 0.30.0.  I have a function that returns a promise:

```
function process(callback:Function):Promise {
  return new Promise((r,re) => callback)
}
```

Flow raises an error, complaining:

```
function process(callback:Function):Promise {
                                    ^^^^^^^ Promise. Application of polymorphic type needs <list of 1 argument>. (Can use `*` for inferrable ones)
```

This works in [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE5wgUwM7YBQQCGANsQEaEQDWAXAGLjTxgCUNACugLYzaaIBvAFCJEqTFBCokYTAHdEnODz548qADTiWiALwA+REVIVqLIQF8gA), but not locally.  Any ideas of the issue?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

According to the flow changelog there was a change introduced in v0.28.0 which made type arguments explicit. Explicitly setting the return type to `Promise<any>` should fix your issue.

Alternatively you can set the following flag to false, although this is a temporary flag which will be removed in the future

`experimental.strict_type_args=false`

https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/Changelog.md#v0280

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but I've been trying to find the Promise type documentation in Flow Docs (https://flow.org/en/docs/types/) but I couldn't find anything. Where is  it documented?

Comment: @Leonardo I am in the same situation, have you found the docs on it?

Comment: @Noitidart kind of, I had to open an [issue on github](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4882) where they pointed me to the code implementing the Promise Type. Apparently the code exists but it's not documented :\

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing this was figured some time ago and the correct answer to what was going on was that it was a versions mismatch between local and the on-line flow interpreter.

However, as this question turns up near the top of search results when looking for how to Flow annotate Promises, it's probably worth mentioning that the fix for these types of situations is to specify the Flow type that the Promise resolves to as a Flow angle bracket parameter.

In this case adding a "any" to the Promise annotation silences the error e.g. ...

```
function process(callback:Function):Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((r,re) => callback)
}
```

In the docs over [here as well for another example](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#toc-function-returns)