# Flow Types with Promises (Fetch's)

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I created a Fetch function to consume a JSON API and have defined types for the JSON object. I am confused about how to define the return type for the  `getCurrentJobAPI` function since I do a bunch of `.then()` afterwards. Is the return value the last .then()? In my code, the last .then() is a setState, so what would the type be for that?

```
    getCurrentJobAPI = (): {} => {

        const url: string = `dummy_url&job_id=${this.props.currentJob}`;

        return fetch(url, {credentials: 'include'})
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((json: CurrentJob) => {
                console.log(json);
                const location = json.inventoryJob.location;
                const ref_note = json.inventoryJob.note;
                const id = json.inventoryJob.id;
                const models = json.inventoryJobDetails.map((j) => {
                    return Object.assign({}, {
                        code: j.code,
                        qty: j.qty
                    })
                });
                this.setState({ currentCodes: models, location: location, ref_note: ref_note, id: id})
                return json
            })
            .then((json: CurrentJob) => {
            const barcodes = json.inventoryJob.history;
            if (barcodes.length > 0) {
                this.setState({apiBarcodes: barcodes})
            }
            this.calculateRows();
            this.insertApiBarcodes();
            this.setState({ initialLoad: true });
            })
    };
```

**UPDATE**:

Although I understand that I am supposed to define `Promise<type>` as the return value of `getCurrentJobAPI` (see [Gilad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5448234/gilad-bar)'s answer and comments), I am still unsure why I can't write `Promise<CurrentJob>` if the Fetch resolves as the JSON response.

[I have condensed my .then() statements per [loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/loganfsmyth)'s recommondation.]

Here are the type definitions for `CurrentJob`:

```
type Job = {
    user_id: number,
    status: 'open' | 'closed',
    location: 'string',
    history: {[number]: string}[],
    note: string,
} & CommonCurrentJob;

type JobDetails = {
    iaj_id: number,
    code: number,
} & CommonCurrentJob;


type CommonCurrentJob = {
    id: number,
    qty: number,
    qty_changed: number,
    created_at: string,
    updated_at: string
}
```

Comment: The return value is the entire promise chain. You could technically take the result of `getCurrentJobAPI()` and attach more `then` and `catch` type things to it. Is that what you were asking? Otherwise I'm not sure what to say. You can't return anything other than the promise itself, because otherwise it would no longer be asynchronous.

Comment: If the return value is the entire promise chain, how can I define the type of Promise in Flow? Where is the documentation for such a case?

Comment: You can't. That's not how async would work. If you tried running code _after_ the promise chain, it would possibly run _before_ the promise gets to the end. So you can't think of it as returning a value, because that is synchronous

Comment: Sorry, just realised that I haven't understood your question. My bad

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but almost none of those `.then`s are needed. You use `.then` either to return another promise, or as the final handler in a promise chain. Most of your intermediate `.then` handlers just end up returning `undefined` so you could collapse them into the first `.then`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So first off, a disclaimer, I am a TypeScript user but I find that this question is actually applicable to both languages and has the same answer.

> I created a Fetch function to consume a JSON API and have defined types for the JSON object. I am confused about how to define the return type for the  getCurrentJobAPI function since I do a bunch of .then() afterwards. Is the return value the last .then()? In my code, the last .then() is a setState, so what would the type be for that?

TL;DR: `Promise<void>` (see note). As you suspect, this is in fact the return type of the last top-level `.then` in the promise chain.

Now lets dig a bit deeper

Here is your example, reworked very slightly to leverage type inference instead of annotating callback parameters that are declared as `any` by their receivers.

*As an aside, these callback parameter annotations amount to unsafe implicit casts, or type assertions as we call them in TypeScript, and they lie about the shape of the code. They look like this*

```
declare function takesFn(fn: (args: any) => any): void;
```

*So I have minimized these since they form a subtle trap*

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';

type CurrentJob = {
    inventoryJob: Job,
    inventoryJobDetails: JobDetails[]
}

export default class A extends React.Component<{currentJob:JobDetails}, any> {

  getCurrentJobAPI: () => Promise<void> = () => {

        const url = `dummy_url&job_id=${String(this.props.currentJob)}`;

        return fetch(url, {credentials: 'include'})
            .then(response => {
                return (response : {json(): any}).json();
            }) // --> Promise<any>
            .then(json => {

                const currentJob = (json: CurrentJob); // make the assumption explicit.

                console.log(currentJob);

                const {location, id, note: ref_note} = currentJob.inventoryJob;

                const currentCodes = currentJob.inventoryJobDetails
                  .map(({code, qty}) => ({
                    code,
                    qty
                  }));

                this.setState({currentCodes, location, ref_note, id});
                return currentJob;
            }) // --> Promise<CurrentJob>
            .then(currentJob => {
                const apiBarcodes = currentJob.inventoryJob.history;
                if (apiBarcodes.length > 0) {
                    this.setState({apiBarcodes});
                }
                this.setState({initialLoad: true});
            }); // --> Promise<void>
    };
}
```

So I am making assertions about the promises in each `then` call above but those assertions are all validated by type inference with the exception of the initial type cast on the response value.

As further evidence, if we remove the type declaration from the `getCurrentJobAPI` property of `A`, flow will infer that its type is in fact `Promise<void>`.

Bonus: simplifying with `async`/`await`. I've used several ESNext features above to shorten the code and make it a bit more pleasant, but we can leverage a specific feature, `async`/`await` to make it easier to understand control flow and types in `Promise` based code.

Consider this revision.

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';

type CurrentJob = {
    inventoryJob: Job,
    inventoryJobDetails: JobDetails[]
}

export default class A extends React.Component<{currentJob:JobDetails}, any> {
    getCurrentJobAPI = async () => {

        const url = `dummy_url&job_id=${String(this.props.currentJob)}`;

        const response = await fetch(url, {credentials: 'include'});
        const json = await response.json();
        const currentJob = (json: CurrentJob); // make the assumption explicit.

        console.log(currentJob);

        const {location, id, note: ref_note} = currentJob.inventoryJob;

        const currentCodes = currentJob.inventoryJobDetails.map(({code, qty}) => ({
            code,
            qty
        }));

        this.setState({currentCodes, location, ref_note, id});


        const apiBarcodes = currentJob.inventoryJob.history;
        if (apiBarcodes.length > 0) {
            this.setState({apiBarcodes});
        }
        this.setState({initialLoad: true});

    };
}
```

Clearly, this is a `void` function. It has no `return` statements. However, as an `async` function, it inherently returns a `Promise`, just as it did when written as an explicit `Promise` chain.

**Note:** `void` is a construct that has been found useful in Flow and TypeScript to represent the semantic intent of function that do not return values but in reality such functions actually return `undefined` because, well, this is JavaScript. Flow does not seem to recognize `undefined` as a type, but under TypeScript, the function could equally be annotated as returning `Promise<undefined>`. Irregardless, `Promise<void>` is preferable thanks to the clarity of intent it provides.

**Remarks:** I worked through this using a combination of https://flow.org/try and the flow binary for Windows. The experience on Windows is really terrible and hopefully it will improve.

Answer (score 1):

When chaining then's, the result will always be a promise.
When calling `then`, the return value is another promise, otherwise chaining then's wouldn't have been possible.
You can see that easily by using console.log() surrounding the entire chain.

Comment: So how exactly would I define the return type of my function? Do I define a type which encompasses the entire chain?

Comment: The return type in this case would be Promise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38730646/using-promise-as-return-type-in-flow

Comment: Not yet, does Promise itself require a type? Like Promise<any> or the like?

Comment: @AvremelKaminetzky Yes, in Flow Promise is a type generating type (i.e. it take s a type as parameter and internally generates a type base don that), so you have to specify a type for the promise, for example `Promise<string>` for a promise that resolves with a string. You can also use `Promise<*>` to let Flow figure it out, and `Promise<any>` to prevent Flow from checking the actual type of the promise (not recommended, `any` should only be used when you have no other option).

Comment: @Mörre my q is what is the type of the Promise if it evolves over the `.then()` chain.

Comment: @AvremelKaminetzky Whatever the promise resolves with! Of course, this requires that you actually understand your promise chain - i.e. minus types, just the thing itself? If you don't fully "get" promises it is hard to talk about types. You must understand your code first. `getCurrentJobAPI` resolves with what the last element of the promise chain returns. The type of that thing is the type of the promise - because it always returns a promise, you just have to find out what that promise resolves with.

Comment: I have console.log'd my code. At the first stage the output is `Promise { "pending" }`. At the last stage the output is my JSON obj (`CurrentJob`). If so the final resolve of Promise is CurrentJob. Why do I get an error when writing `Promise<CurrentJob>`?

Comment: Because the type is json, not CurrentJob

Comment: But CurrentJob is the type definition of my Json object? I must be missing something.

Comment: @AvremelKaminetzky JSON is a string format. You either have a JSON `string`(!!!) - or you have an object. There is no such thing as a "JSON object", in fact that term is a contradiction in itself, like "ice-fire". You can _encode_ an object as a JSON string. But then you have a string. Which contains an object, but only if you decode it.